# Not able to check two sixes generated through Randint() in a Looop

Tags: python

The code I have used for this purpose if only checking the single six's in the loop

here it is

```
from random import *
trial = randint(1, 6)
print(trial)
counter = 0

last_dice = randint(1, 6)
print(last_dice, end='')

for i in range(trial-1):
    new_dice = randint(1, 6)
    print(new_dice, end='')
    if last_dice == 6 and new_dice == 6:
        last_dice = new_dice
        counter += 1

print()
print(counter)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is the output different than what you expected? If so, please elaborate. If `last_dice` gets an initial value different than 6, it will never change and `counter` will remain at 0.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve here? It's not quite clear to me what's wrong because I don't know what it's supposed to do

Comment: Dear the code is just giving me result for the single 6. Its not checking the 66

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to reset the last_dice outside the if:

```
from random import *
trial = randint(1, 6)
print(trial)
counter = 0

last_dice = randint(1, 6)
print(last_dice, end='')

if last_dice == 6 and new_dice == 6:
    counter += 1
    last_dice=0
else:
    last_dice = new_dice
print()
print(counter)
```

Comment: Thanks bro that worked but the problem still persist as the triple are also been counted.. I want only 66 to be added to the counter.. 666 are also being counted as 2 in counter

Comment: @WaqarRafique , I have made a change to cope with the triple six scenario

Comment: dear thank you very very much for doing this for me. You are awesome.

Comment: Happy to help, if you are happy with the answer please accept it and vote it up. Thanks!

Comment: need little bit of more help here. I was trying to check the same numbers for the longest sequence of successive rolls in which 6 is not appearing, It appears that same task needed some improvements. Hopefully I am trying to accomplish that with functions. One for the double six and second for the longest sequence of successive rolls. please do help me with that. Thanks

Comment: dear I just updated my code to use the same result for dice for any other function. please help needed.

Comment: @WaqarRafique As it seems that you are building up the code, I suggest you to raise a new question and post the code you now have and the specific problem you are now trying to resolve.

Comment: I have just posted the question with new code. please do help me with it.

Comment: @WaqarRafique I posted my answer on that one now. You were very close actually just a bit of tidy up at the end of the fuction

Comment: need your help with one more function on the result. I am trying to right up the code. For example in 5533661656, I want to find the sequence with 5's and 6's only. There are three, 2 sequence with length 2 and 1 with length 3 and want to print the frequent series which is 2. How can I get started. To make my self clear 616161666 result is 1, 456116513656124566 result is 3 and 56611166626634416 is also 3.  In 456116513656124566 length of 2 and 3 occur twice, there is a tie between them. Now the length of the longest (that is 3) should be printed